# How can I redirect the users after confirmation basing on the roles they have?

Tags: users, rules

I have two type of users, and I have created two types of registration forms for each role. I want to redirect the users to different pages, once they get the email confirmation according to their roles.

For example:

- user1, with the first role, must be redirected to page1
- user2, with the second role, must be redirected to page2

I think I can achieve this feature using the Rules module, but I don't know how to do it.

Can you tell me how can I implement it?

Answer (score 4):

yes, with Rules!

1. create a new rule.
2. select event: user has logged in (or if you use LoginTobogan module you can use the event "When the user account is validated".)
3. select condition: User has role(s), and assign the role (I recommend create a new Role and assign this role to a test user)
4. selet the action: Page redirect, and add the url to the destination
   (I have selected `'Immediately issue the page redirect'` to see the redirection (if is not select this, I can not see working the redirection, but test if you does not need this. Please review the warning about the setting)
5. enable your rule and test.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use something like the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module to achieve what you want. If not, there might be a solution in using the Trigger and Rules modules.

Comment: logintoboggan module will redirect all type of user to single page. but i want to redirect some type of users to particular page and another type of users to another page.Can you tell me how can i implement it by rules?